# Error Create Canvas not defined- While trying to save sample project

Tags: p5.js, adobe-brackets

I am trying to learn Java Script and I referring to Daniel Shiffman videos. I have installed Bracket and have downloaded the example project, On writing an implementation for setup and draw method I am getting the error [ERROR: createCanvas is not defined] in the ESLint(4) editor console.

I have attached the screenshot for reference.
[image]

referred the link (https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20819/getting-started-with-p5-js-using-brackets-having-problems) but that did not resolve my issue.
The video that I am looking in is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmZbhManVcY

**Update: When I click on Index.html it opens perfectly fine in the browser. The problem is only at the editor.**
**Index.html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>p5.js example</title>
   <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
   <script src="p5.js"></script>
   <script src="p5.sound.js"></script>
   <script src="sketch.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
</body>
```

OputPut:
[image]

Comment: What does your `index.html` file look like?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I have added the index.html in the updated section of question.

Comment: Can you check the network tab of your developer tools? Is it correctly loading the `.js` files?